# Can physical credit card reader identify first & last name?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, payment-processing, credit-card-track-data

I'm looking into how physical credit card readers work, like the ones in grocery store. Can they identify who is paying, e.g. first name & last name that is printed on a credit card? What kind of data do they get? Do physical card readers get credit card number or just some token?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

What data can a card reader potentially obtain? A basic swiper (typically replaced in US by EMV) can read Track 1 data, including Primary account number (PAN), Name, Expiration date. If the card reader is encrypted, only the application that has the key can obtain the data.

In a retail environment using US EMV chip terminals like the Verifone MX915 or similar Ingenico, the terminal is usually a slave to a payment gateway. What happens in that environment, including all data exchange, token, etc is all part of the EMV certification. You can read more about that here https://www.emvco.com/processes-forms/product-approval/

Answer (score 0):

Sort answer, no.  When you visit a store and pay by card, they will send the card information (card number and expiry date) along with how much to debit your account to a payment gateway - they will route the request to the relevant merchant bank.  They are responsible for contacting your bank to debit the account.  **The bank, and only the bank, has identifiable information.**  You prove your identity to the seller by presenting your signature or PIN.  If you're paying online, you must provide identity information to prove who you are.

Comment: can the owner of card reader get some unique credit card ID (like card number) or completely nothing?

Comment: I should probably add, the name printed (or embossed) on the card helps the seller further identify you with additional identification.

Comment: @Gintas_ I am not sure I understand your question.  The card number is unique.  It helps the bank identify which bank account to debit the payment from.

Comment: This wiki article explains card numbers very well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number

Comment: yeah, but let's say if I, as a credit card reader owner (seller), wanted to make a software to uniquely identify credit card for analytics purposes, is there a way? Let's say count how many times this card was used for transactions in my store

Comment: Depending on local laws you're treading into dodgy grounds.  Here within the UK, you have to be PCI compliant (I think this applies worldwide but I maybe wrong).  Most of this talks about data security.  When I was considering storing card details, I was going to encrypt those details but after reading the guidelines I ran away kicking and screaming.

Comment: Useful link on this: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

Comment: true with PCI, but the question is, is there even a way to retrieve credit card number if you have a physical card reader or is it a closed system?

Comment: Nope, that is what a card reader does, reads the data stored on the magnetic stripe or the chip embedded with the card. You'll need to check with the provider of the hardware if there is an API you can plug into, and if they have any documentation.

Comment: Um, you can 100% get first name, last name and card number from the magnetic stripe without contacting anyone.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card#Financial_cards

Answer (score 0):

All payment cards contain the cardholder name, card number (PAN), expiry date and issue number (where applicable) in digital format - encoded both on the magnetic stripe and on the EMV chip where present.

This data can be read by the terminal without contacting any third party, and in fact it must be read to initiate contact with third party gateway in order to perform authorization/settlement